# how to deal with the special code such as # in the sed sentence

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I defined a marco switch in PublicDefine.h to control the target device in my code.

I meant to replace the target sentence automatically according to the options in my build shell.

Below is a peace of my code, I got an error "sed: -e expression #1, char 5: comments don't accept any addresses".

May somebody tell me how to deal with the #? Or you can just give me another suggestion. Thank you!

```
nLine=`grep NO_LCD PublicDefine.h -nR | cut -d ":" -f 1`
dfine_nolcd="#define NO_LCD 1"
ndfine_nolcd="#undef NO_LCD "
echo $dfine_nolcd   #this is a debugging sentence
echo $ndfine_nolcd  #this is a debugging sentence
echo "nLine  $nLine"

if [ "$1"x = "NO_LCD"x ]; then
    sed -i "${nLine} ${dfine_nolcd}" PublicDefine.h 
else
    sed -i "${nLine} ${ndfine_nolcd}" PublicDefine.h
fi
```

Comment: The syntax for a `sed` replace command is `s/pattern/replace/flags`, where  any character can be used instead of the `/`. You don't seem to respect that syntax?

Comment: I see the sentece 
sed -i  '2 cxxxx' file   can make it!

I just made it by
sed -i "${nLine} c${dfine_nolcd}" PublicDefine.h

I missed out the 'c'.

Comment: as an aside, you can just use `[ "$1" = "NO_LCD" ]` without the `x`'s as you have quoted the variable properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i '2 c xyz' file
```

can be used to replace the given line of file by "xyz".

The below sentence solved my problem:

```
sed -i "${nLine} c ${dfine_nolcd}" PublicDefine.h
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as you noticed, the problem you had was that you gave `sed` a line number and a string, but not a command. It took the `#` sign in your string as a command starting a comment.

But finding out the line number is still not necessary, as `sed` can match lines based on their contents instead of a line number, so you could just use something like these:

Change any line containing `NO_LCD` with a given string:

```
sed -e '/NO_LCD/c#define NO_LCD 1' PublicDefine.h
```

(`/regex/` - on lines matching the regex, `c` - change line to following string.)

Or unconditionally try to do a string replacement over the full line:

```
sed -e 's/^.*NO_LCD.*$/#define NO_LCD 1/' PublicDefine.h
```

Assuming `PublicDefine.h` contains

```
something
NO_LCD replace me
something
```

both print

```
something
#define NO_LCD 1
something
```

Comment: It's a little difficult for me to understand your code, I tested it , and It show me an error:
: No such file or directorye.h

Comment: ok. I run : 
    `sed -e '/NO_LCD/c#define NO_LCD 1' PublicDefine.h`

then run
    `grep NO_LCD PublicDefine.h -nR `                    
to get the result:
176:#undef NO_LCD. 


same with 

    `sed -e 's/^.*NO_LCD.*$/#define NO_LCD 3/' PublicDefine.h`.


Is there something different between our enviroment?